# Export stacked layers of images as a thumbnail URL in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, normalized-difference-water-index

I am computing different normalized index like NDVI, NDWI, NDBI, UI and adding them as layers stacked on top of Sentinel 2-1C Image patch.

I would like to download the generated stacked image as a thumbnail (jpg or png) file.

I can do `image.getThumbnailURL` on each layer and extract them as separate thumbnail images, but I want to export the entire stacked-layer as a single image.

*Code Snippet*

```
var LAT = 18.7332794
var LNG = 82.811036 
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([LNG, LAT]).buffer(10000).bounds()

function mask2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}


var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filterDate('2015-06-01', '2015-12-31')
              .filterBounds(geometry)
              .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE').limit(5)
              .map(mask2clouds)
              .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12'])

var median = collection.median()
var roi = median.clip(geometry)

// NDWI: NIR - GREEN
var ndwi = roi.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8'])
var ndwiMasked = ndwi.updateMask(ndwi.gte(0.2))

// NDVI: RED - NIR
var ndvi = roi.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
var ndviMasked = ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.gte(0.2))

// NDBI
var ndbi = roi.normalizedDifference(['B11', 'B8'])
var ndbiMasked = ndbi.updateMask(ndbi.gte(0.05))

// BARE
var bare = ndvi.lt(0.2).and(ndwi.lt(0))
var bareMasked = bare.updateMask(bare)

Map.setCenter(LNG, LAT, 12)

Map.addLayer(roi, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0.0, max: 0.3}, 'roi')
Map.addLayer(ndwiMasked, {'min': 0.5, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['cf92c6', '67001f']}, 'ndwi')
Map.addLayer(ndviMasked, {'min': 0.5, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['98d7c7', '00441b']}, 'ndvi')
Map.addLayer(ndbiMasked, {'min': 0.5, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['fec253', '662506']}, 'ndbi')
Map.addLayer(bareMasked, {}, 'bare')
```

I am attaching the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fc1c11cbf5712d5aa7415df09df1d877) to code editor for reference to what I am trying to achieve.

**Edit**

I am able to concatenate the ndvi, ndwi, ndbi normalized images and extract them as a thumbnail.

*Code Snippet*

```
// NDWI: NIR - GREEN
var ndwi = roi.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8'])
// NDVI: RED - NIR
var ndvi = roi.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
// NDBI
var ndbi = roi.normalizedDifference(['B11', 'B8'])
// BARE
var bare = ndvi.lt(0.2).and(ndwi.lt(0))

var multiband = ee.Image.cat([ndvi, ndwi, ndbi, bare])
var url = multiband.getThumbURL({'min':-1, 'max': 1, 'dimensions': 512, 'format': 'jpeg'})
```

This however adds in a lot more color than masking and adding, which might be complicated for the model I am trying to build.

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c52987db5cc6fc9f3a0b3a3ac7895cfd), is the link to the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

I have never exported as a thumbnail, but from the docs [getThumbURL](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagegetthumburl) it would seem that you need to already have created a multi band image.

```
var fullImage = roi.addBands(ndwiMasked).addBands(ndviMasked)
                   .addBands(ndbiMasked).addBands(bareMasked)
```

And then you get the URL of `fullImage`.  You do have 5 bands, and the RGB requires only 3...

Comment: Thanks, Sean, but this way I won't be able to add specific image parameters for each band.  

for eg: I would like to use a different color palette for NDVI and NDWI bands, but in getThumbURL, I can pass only one Image viz parameters, like:
```var url = fullImage.getThumbURL({'min': 0.0, 'max': 0.3})```